# How to compile emscripten library using emcc on windows code from linux bash

Tags: windows, shell, webassembly, emscripten

I would like to run command from tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/emscripting-a-c-library

The command that I would like to run is:

```
$ emcc -O3 -s WASM=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]' \
    -I libwebp \
    webp.c \
    libwebp/src/{dec,dsp,demux,enc,mux,utils}/*.c
```

The syntax from the code above is from linux and I can not run it on windows cmd nor power shell. How to do it?

Comment: Most parts of that command will work just fine as is on windows.

The file globbing part I guess is that part of that won't.. you would need to find some way to pass all those to the compiler.   

I guess you could do `libwebp\src\dec\* libwebp\src\dsp\*` since I imagine that the * works as expected on windows.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work: `emcc -O3 -s WASM=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]' -I libwebp webp.c libwebp\src\dec\*`, the error is: `emcc: error: libwebp\src\dec\*.c: No such file or directory ("libwebp\src\dec\*.c" was expected to be an input file, based on the commandline arguments provided)`. As you mentioned, globbing part is not working. When I put path to a single file in `dec` folder, shell finds the file.

Comment: You'll need to manually expand the glob or use corresponding shell's capabilities - for example, in PowerShell you should be able to use `emcc -O3 ... webp.c (ls libwebp/src/*.c)` to expand the wildcard.